# Using ArrayList or HashMap

Tags: arraylist, hashmap

Hi I got a question on whether to use an `ArrayList` or `HashMap`.

I am trying to build a Paint program.
Each drawn object will be assigned a unique object `ID`.

If I want a fast retrieval speed when I click on an object, should I be using an `arraylist` or `hashmap`?

In general hashmap has O(1) while arraylist has O(n) retrieval speed.

However, I think for my case, since when I click on an object, I'll get the ID, hence the index of the array and I can do something like ArraylistObject.get(ithElement); , so in this case this will also be a O(1) retrieval process?

any inputs?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your ID the same as your index in array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If objects have an ID that can be mapped 1-to-1 to an array than that will be O(1) access as well, and in practice will be slightly faster than a hashmap lookup (you don't have to compute the hash).

However, the issue will be what happens when you delete an object.  You will be left with a hole in the list.  When creating new objects you can then keep appending to the list and leave it to get slowly more fragmented or try and find a spare slot in which case you'll be doing an O(n) search for a spare space.

In short - a hashmap is probably more appropriate.

Comment: If its an ArrayList in Java Collections, then the array should be contiguous even after deleting an object (forget the implementation details). However, if object ID is same as the array index, the behavior will be even weirder as after deleting a certain object, ID's may start pointing to a whole new object as everything shifts up to fill the gap. So definitely a HashMap.

Comment: Apologies, forgot that ArrayList reshuffles the underlying array when an element is removed (been a while since I did Java), but yes your point is very valid that the references will then be screwed up.

Comment: The whole point of using the ID as index is that you would not delet entries, but set them to null.

Comment: So my original point stands - you drift towards a sparsely populated list over time.  Question is does finding and reusing slots or resizing the array and appending work out cheaper than just using a hashmap?  Suspect it's a non-issue given the type of application (human driven) so I'd still stick with a hashmap as it's a more intuitive structure for holding objects with unique keys.

Answer (score 1):

On the plus side, you might be able to squeeze out a little extra performance by doing ArrayLists just right.
But deleting objects is going to be a royal pain - as Paolo and Anurag said, you'll either have to put an empty placeholder (null ?) or to renumber some other other object to fill the gap.
This is likely to result in performance bugs and plain old bugs.

HashMaps, on the other hand. Simple to use, decent performance guaranteed (unless you allocate your ids really badly).

And retrieving objects by id might not turn out to be your application's bottleneck at all. As the saying goes, *premature optimization is the root of all evil*.

Answer (score 1):

*If* you can guarantee that the IDs will be in a relatively small numerical range, then you should use a plain array (with the size preinitialized to the maximum ID), rather than an `ArrayList`. That ensures that you don't accidentally remove entries and shift everything else to fill the gap, with everything ending up at a wrong index. A plain array will also be a bit faster than an ArrayList.

If you can't make such a guarantee, use a HashMap. It's very unlikely that the speed difference would be noticeable, and it will be easier to maintain.